# Can I use present perfect in this context?

Tags: present-perfect, perfect-constructions

> After finishing my homework I will check for the mistakes that I **have made**

I'm skeptical about if I can use present perfect in this context and
besides with conjunction can present perfect be used for future?

Comment: The present perfect is fine in your example, but could you please add more information why you think it's wrong?   That way we can provide a detailed explanation to teach you how to use it in this kind of sentence.  Otherwise, the question might be closed.

Comment: There is nothing ungrammatical there. Semantically, you might want to say *I will check for* ***any*** *mistakes that I* ***may*** *have made*. But what is the source of your concern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the present perfect in conjunction with the future tense.  English often depends on the *perspective* from which you want the listener to *view* some event, which can subtly change the information you want to convey.

In this case, the present perfect would be fine, if that's your intended perspective:

> After I finish my homework, I will check for any mistakes **I've made**.

This perspective is from the future condition, looking at mistakes which you may have just finished making.

In addition, you could use the past perfect, the simple present, or the simple past, to establish other, subtly different perspectives:

> After I finish my homework, I will check for any mistakes **I'd made**.

This perspective is from the future situation, looking back on past mistakes you made before finishing.

> After I finish my homework, I will check for any mistakes **I make**.

This perspective is from the current moment, looking forward to any mistakes you might make.

> After I finish my homework, I will check for any mistakes **I made**.

This perspective is from the future, looking back on any past mistakes.

In addition, as Jason Brassford mentions in his comment, it's common to add a qualifier to the sentence to establish that you don't actually *intend* to make mistakes:

> After I finish my homework, I will check for any mistakes I **may/might** have made.

Comment: I'd made seems dubious, at least in your description, what is the pluperfect there for? it might work for some mistakes made before the homework was started at all. Otherwise, the case is exhausted with have made, made and make, modals apart, imo.

Comment: @MvLog  I wouldn't worry too much about the logic of it.  The point is that any of these *can* be used, and not that you, personally, might choose to use them, especially if you feel they don't make logical sense. The perfect tense can elegantly convey the relationship between two events, and while in this case it's kind of a moot point, in another context it might be more significant.

Comment: @andrew what does may have mean ? does it mean the same as will have in this context?

Comment: @user82287  "may" and "might" add elements of *uncertainty* or *possibility*. "Will" is more *definite*.  **I may go to the party** (= I'm not sure if I will go), **He may have made a mistake** (= I'm not sure if he has made a mistake).  .

Comment: okay btw to me only present perfect sounds idiomatic. How can I look for mistakes before finishing the work?

Comment: @user82287  Well, again, this is one of the weird things about English, that we change the verb or verb tense to match the intended *perspective*.  For example, "**Come** with me to the party?" vs. "**Go** with me to the party?"   In your example, any mistakes you **will make** (from now),  in the future, you **will already have made**.  From this future perspective, the mistakes are all in the past.

Comment: @user82287  fortunately these kind of examples are rare in any language, so all this is mostly just playing around with verb tenses to understand what *can* be said.  There are simpler ways to say all of these, e.g. **After I finish my homework I'll check it for mistakes**.

Comment: okay but there is one more sentence in my mind that is confusing me.  After the party I'll unbox all the presents that I have gotten.    (i guess it  would mean after the party I'll unbox all the presents that I will have gotten)

Comment: but what if the party is already going on. And I mean to unbox the presents that I have already received now

Comment: @user82287  It's the same.  You sentence is from the perspective of "after the party", which is in the future.  Also FYI (at least in the US) we would say **unwrap** or **open** presents that you **have received**.   "Unbox" sounds more *industrial*, and "gotten" (for some reason) doesn't sound as nice as *received*.

Comment: after the party I'll unwrap the presents that I have received (i would interpret it as will have recieved)

Comment: but currently the party is going on and I mean after this party ends I will unwrap the presents that I have recieved (that is already on the gift table)